# Mopub VAST ad unit id for testing

Tags: android, mopub

I want to test VAST ads on mopub Android SDK. Is there any ad unit id provided by mopub to test VAST ads or do I have to create one on app.mopub.com for testing?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create an ad unit id and associated creative (through an Order and direct serve line item) on the MoPub website app.mopub.com.

You can set up your own test direct serve creative by creating an Order and Line Item and add the creative of the ad format you are trying to test.

To do this, follow the documentation below to set up a Order and Line item and also add a creative to the line item.

https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ui/setup

https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ui/settings

https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ui/adding-creative

In you select Fullscreen for the Ad Format when adding the creative, there will be the option to select VAST for creative in which you can enter the VAST XML for the creative.

The changes will take up to 20 minutes to update to MoPub's adservers and you should be able to request the ad unit on the MoPub Sample App the line item is targeted to to test the creative.

Comment: Isnt there a predefined adunit id to test vast video from mopub?

Comment: Hey,

MoPub does not have a predetermined test ad for VAST testing, but you can use the example tag that was used for testing in the SDK here.

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sdk/src/test/java/com/mopub/mobileads/VastXmlManagerTest.java

Answer (score 0):

Check out their sample on [Github](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk).

I am directing here directly to [resource file](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sample/res/values/strings.xml) where they store 
adUnit Ids.

I have **tested ad_unit_id_banner**, **ad_unit_id_interstitial**, **ad_unit_id_rewarded_video** out of all and they worked immediately.